# SQL Buddy , mySQL Error for LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, sqlbuddy

I am trying to import a CSV file into mysql database. but the query is giving error. The query is :

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ‘/last.csv’ INTO TABLE punjab FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ ENCLOSED BY ‘”‘ LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\r\n’ (newpoll, blockcode, halqa, pollnumber, pollstation, sex, area);
```

and the error is

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '‘/last.csv’ INTO TABLE punjab FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘,’ ENCLOSED BY ‘�' at line 1
```

Any ideas ??
thanks

Comment: You're using `‘` and `’` as apostrophes; you probably need to use `'` for both.

Comment: sql uses `'` for quoting. don't use so-called-smart-quotes-that-really-are-moronic `‘` and `’`

Answer (score 1):

you could have used http://www.whereismyballot.com ;) by the way, you shouldn't have quoted the field names